# React Router all links open same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I use my grid component in all *Listesi page.And when i try to navigate using grid page always open UListesi page.But other *Kayit pages are working correctly.

```
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
      <Route name="SListesi" path="S" handler={SListesi}/>
        <Route name="GListesi" handler={GListesi}/>

      <Route name="UListesi" path="U" handler={UListesi}/>
 </Route>
```

My *Listesi Pages

```
  /** @jsx React.DOM */
defaultColumns = ["ID","Name"];
externalColumns = [["x",EditRows],["a",EditRows]];
dataUrl = "/C/";

var CListesi = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
    return (<AjaxGridComponent dataUrl={dataUrl} filter={true} controllerName={'c'} showExternalColumn={true} externalColumns={externalColumns} defaultColumns={defaultColumns} />);
    }
});
/** @jsx React.DOM */
defaultColumns = ["Name","Price"];
externalColumns = [["",EditRows]];
dataUrl = "/U/";
var UListesi = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (<AjaxGridComponent dataUrl={dataUrl} filter={true} controllerName={'u'} showExternalColumn={true} externalColumns={externalColumns} defaultColumns={defaultColumns} />);
    }
});
```

Comment: in the example you have provided, you define `dataUrl = "/Urun/";` twice in a more-global scope. So in both cases it will use that as the dataUrl. Same goes for `defaultColumns` and `externalColumns` - are these separated by scope somehow?

Comment: thank you. i use  componentWillMount: function () {this.defaultColumns = [...],...}